# A Convention Travel Document (CTD) or Titre de Voyage

Tags: visas, uk, refugees, australian-residents

I have an Australian travel document for refugees. Do I need a visa to travel to London?

Comment: https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y

Comment: @Beatriz Sanchez Scroll down the list of countries from the link provided by Michael Hampton and select ‘Stateless or Refugee’. I think the answer will be ‘Yes, you need a visa’ but it’s impossible to say without more information about you and the trip.

Comment: What is your nationality and do you have a passport for that?

Comment: @Mast A refugee cannot use their national passport

Comment: @Traveller That's going to make travelling complicated.

Comment: @Mast Not particularly - most countries accept Australian CTDs for visa issuance purposes, and a few allow visa-free entry https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Australian_Convention_Travel_Document